# The Right Way of Intercepting Javascript Function Calls

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools-events

I am writing a browser extension for the popular video chatting platform, Omegle.
The extension needs access to internal events of the omegle app. The app uses Mootools for firing events, and creates a new global object **(COMETBackend)** that inherits the Events class of mootools. I am trying to intercept function calls to the fireEvent function of the COMETBackend object, by injecting this code into the DOM:

```
let proxy = COMETBackend.prototype.fireEvent;

COMETBackend.prototype.fireEvent =  function (...args) {
    console.log(...args)
    return proxy(...args);
}
```

Events Class from Mootools.js

```
var Events = new Class({
    $events: {},
    addEvent: function(c, b, a) {
        c = Events.removeOn(c);
        if (b != $empty) {
            this.$events[c] = this.$events[c] || [];
            this.$events[c].include(b);
            if (a) {
                b.internal = true;
            }
        }
        return this;
    },
    addEvents: function(a) {
        for (var b in a) {
            this.addEvent(b, a[b]);
        }
        return this;
    },
    fireEvent: function(c, b, a) {
        c = Events.removeOn(c);
        if (!this.$events || !this.$events[c]) {
            return this;
        }
        this.$events[c].each(function(d) {
            d.create({
                bind: this,
                delay: a,
                "arguments": b
            })();
        }, this);
        return this;
    },
    removeEvent: function(b, a) {
        b = Events.removeOn(b);
        if (!this.$events[b]) {
            return this;
        }
        if (!a.internal) {
            this.$events[b].erase(a);
        }
        return this;
    },
    removeEvents: function(c) {
        var d;
        if ($type(c) == "object") {
            for (d in c) {
                this.removeEvent(d, c[d]);
            }
            return this;
        }
        if (c) {
            c = Events.removeOn(c);
        }
        for (d in this.$events) {
            if (c && c != d) {
                continue;
            }
            var b = this.$events[d];
            for (var a = b.length; a--; a) {
                this.removeEvent(d, b[a]);
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
});
```

COMETBackend Object from Omegle.js

```
var COMETBackend = new Class({
    Implements: [Options, Events],
    initialize: function(a) {
        this.setOptions(a),
            this.clientID = null,
            this.stopped = !1
    }....
```

Now, in the console, the interception seems to have worked as i get the event logs i needed, but omegle for some reason is not responding to those events now, so the interception seems to have broken app's functionality.

Any ideas as to why that happened? am i not intercepting the calls properly?

Comment: Do you really need to override and "intercept" the firing of events, or would just attaching an event listener suffice?

Comment: Did you read the docs of `Class` (or read its code)? I'd guess its mixin approach (`Implements`) does not cope with overwriting prototype methods.

Comment: @Bergi i was so caught up in wanting to override the fireEvent method, the easy solution you mentioned of simply adding an event listener flew right over my head, seems like it is possible to add an event listener, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let proxy = COMETBackend.prototype.fireEvent;
return proxy(...args);
```

Invoking proxy this way causes its 'this' parameter to be lost. Instead:

```
return proxy.apply(this, args)
```